# How to check if a string is a substring of another even if not in order?

Tags: python, string

Is there a way to check if a string contains another string but not necessairely in the correct order :

```
"hel my frend" in "hello my friend" = true
"hel my frend" in "my friend hello" = true
"hel my frend" in "h.e.l. .m.y. .f.r.e.n.d" = true
"hel my frend" in "my friend hello" = true
```

Comment: Why is the second one false?

Comment: if you change your substring to regex or loop over it

Comment: You can split the first string and check for every word.

Comment: @depperm the question says: 'not necessairely in the correct order'.

Comment: Your wording makes it sound like order should be irrelevant?

Comment: whelp. that false is now true. there goes all my work. And also those of some answers so far.

Comment: sorry i refixed the question that was an error

Comment: Let's close until the OP understans what he wants.

Comment: the answer is properly asked now i rechecked everything

Comment: 2nd and 4th examples are identical.

Comment: no the order is not the same

Answer (score 2):

Change the substring to a regular expression with `.*` between each character, and then use `re.search`.

```
import re

def fuzzy_substring(needle, haystack):
    regex = ".*".join(re.escape(char) for char in needle)
    return re.search(regex, haystack)
```

`re.escape` is necessary in case any characters in the substring have special meaning in regular expressions.

Answer (score 1):

You can use programmatically constructed regular expressions for it:

```
import re

def find_string(where, target):
    re_string = '.*'.join(target)
    REGEX = re.compile(re_string)
    return REGEX.findall(where)

print(find_string("hello my friend", "hel my frend"))
print(find_string("my friend hello", "hel my frend"))
print(find_string("h.e.l. .m.y. .f.r.e.n.d", "hel my frend"))
```

will print:

```
['hello my friend']
[]
['h.e.l. .m.y. .f.r.e.n.d']
```

So if the result of function contains 0 elements, it is equal to False, if 1 or more - True.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question and the examples correctly, you could use [`colections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) to count the characters in both strings and see if there are any chars left after subtracting the second from the first.

```
from collections import Counter    
def isin(a, b):
    return not Counter(a) - Counter(b)
```

Positive examples:

```
isin("hel my frend", "hello my friend") # True
isin("hel my frend", "my friend hello") # True
isin("hel my frend", "h.e.l. .m.y. .f.r.e.n.d") # True
```

Negative Exampels:

```
isin("hel my frgend", "hello my friend") # False
isin("hel my frend", "my frind hello") # False
isin("hel my frend", "h.e.l. .m.. .f.r.e.n.d") # False
```

Answer (score 1):

Python 3.10 added comparison operators to `collections.Counter`

```
from collections import Counter
a = Counter("hel my friend")
b = Counter("hello my friend")

is_a_in_b = a <= b  # True
```